# Can't access API's documentation with JHipster

Tags: spring, jhipster, swagger-ui, springfox

I've been trying to access the generated Swagger-UI of a JHipster generated Spring app. I've tried to access through "/swagger-ui.html" as that worked out just fine with other projects, but not this time. I've also looked up the security configuration class and tried all URLs that reference swagger (like "/swagger-ui/index.html") but none of them work: It's response code 404.

I know that the configuration class gets run, because the console shows the "Started Swagger" message, but still no UI.

Any ideas? Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe wrong port.. It should be 8080

Comment: Nope! I actually get redirected to the default error page of JHipster

Answer (score 3):

To access the Swagger docs on a JHipster app, you need to go login as an admin and click the "API" link in the admin navbar dropdown.

You can also access it directly at http://localhost:8080/#/docs

Comment: Hi.. is it possible to easily offer the swagger ui to a normal (ROLE_USER) user ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you made sure that the swagger profile is active? 
Check your config at `src/main/resources/config/application-dev.yml`

```
spring:
    profiles:
        active: dev
        include: swagger
```

or

```
spring:
    profiles:
        active: dev, swagger
```

Answer (score 2):

since you  are using jhipster, you can find the swagger config @ class SwaggerAutoConfiguration in the jar : jhipster-framework

by default the url is : http://127.0.0.1:8761/swagger-ui/index.html
[image]

Comment: the default port is 8080  ... unless you changed it.

Comment: JHipster Registry (Netflix Eureka) is 8761 as you can see my screen shot,  8080 is JHipster application back-end development port (Spring Boot server)

Comment: for me, I don't use Netflix Eureka, and swagger works on http://127.0.0.1:8080/swagger-ui/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
...
compile 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2'
```

or (maven)

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
 <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
 <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Then you'll be able to reach the UI at

http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html

Comment: In my case using Gradle: ```implementation "io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0"```

Answer (score 1):

have a look under ***src/main/webapp/swagger-ui*** to see what resoures have been generated. Also be sure that you run all gulp build stepts, e.g swagger-ui which is included as a task in the build process for the prod environment.

Answer (score 1):

Just created a spring boot JHipster project with v6.10.5. Seems its different now:
Login as admin with password admin. Then on the left of the "account" item at the top the "administration" item appears. Beneath click on "API" or just enter http://localhost:8080/admin/docs.