# Jhipster 7 - swaggerUI not available

Tags: jhipster, swagger-ui

Using JHipster with version 7.1.0 I cannot get the swaggerUI to work.

Running the application with mvnw or from Intellij results with 404 page.
The route I try is http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html.
Api docs are available - both version 3 and 2, but the swagger page is not.

What is even more interesting is the fact that running the application with mvn clean spring-boot:run command - and the swagger page would work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Things have changed from v6, you need an UI and login with admin user. Then, it's available under http://localhost:8080/admin/docs

Refer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40575157/cant-access-apis-documentation-with-jhipster).

Answer (score 0):

You can add dependency swagger-ui into your project.

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then, update maven. The SwaggerUI will be available on :

http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html

Comment: Springfox does not work with Spring Boot 2.6+ and so JHipster switched to Springdoc as of v7.5.0, so probably not a good suggestion to stay with abandoned project. https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/17175